# Oscillatory integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sp.spectral-theory, asymptotics

Consider the integrals

$$I_n(\zeta,\epsilon)=\int_{-\zeta}^\zeta \left|(t-i\epsilon)^{-n}-(t+i\epsilon)^{-n}\right|\,dt$$

I would like to know the asymptotic behavior of $I_n(\zeta,\epsilon)$ for each fixed $\zeta>0$ as $\epsilon$ approaches zero, and hope that this will be independent of $\zeta$. For example, when $n=1$, it is easy to see that $I_1(\zeta,\epsilon)$ tends to $2\pi$ as $\epsilon$ tends to $0$ independent of $\zeta$. Specifically, I would like to understand the cases where $n=\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},\ldots$, but the case of integers would also be interesting.
Note that the question is trivial without the absolute value in the integrand but I would like to see how much does the presence of the absolute value changes the asymptotic behavior.
Thanks,

Comment: For small integer $n$ Mma gives $I_n(\infty,\epsilon)=C_n \epsilon^{1-n}$. To be expected with singularity at the origin.

Comment: That's interesting as without the absolute value there is no singularity at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}
\newcommand{\ep}{\epsilon}$
Take any real $n>0$ and any $z:=\zeta\in(0,\infty)$. Let $\ep\downarrow0$. 
For real $t\ne0$, let $u:=\arctan(\ep/t)$, so that $t=\ep\cot u$. 
Then for $t>0$ 
\begin{equation*}
 \left|(t-i\ep)^{-n}-(t+i\ep)^{-n}\right|=2(t^2+\ep^2)^{-n/2}|\sin(nu)|
 =2\ep^{-n}|\sin(nu)|\,|\sin u|^n   
\end{equation*}
and for $t<0$
\begin{equation*}
 \left|(t-i\ep)^{-n}-(t+i\ep)^{-n}\right|
 =2\ep^{-n}|\sin(n(\pi+u))|\,|\sin u|^n.   
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
 I_n(z,\ep)=2\ep^{1-n}(J_n^+(\de)+J_n^-(\de)),  \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
 \de:=\arctan\frac\ep z\downarrow0, \tag{1a}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 J_n^+(\de):=\int_\de^{\pi/2}|\sin(nu)|(\sin u)^{n-2}\,du
 \to J_n^+(0)\in(0,\infty),  \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
and 
\begin{equation*}
 J_n^-(\de):=\int_{-\pi/2}^{-\de}|\sin(n(\pi+u))|\,|\sin u|^{n-2}\,du
=\int_\de^{\pi/2}|\sin(n(\pi-v))|\,(\sin v)^{n-2}\,dv.   
\end{equation*}

If $n\ge1$, then $J_n^-(\de)\to J_n^-(0)$ and hence 
\begin{equation*}
 I_n(z,\ep)\sim2\ep^{1-n}(J_n^+(0)+J_n^-(0))
 =2\ep^{1-n}\int_0^{\pi/2}(|\sin(nu)|+|\sin(n(\pi-u))|)(\sin u)^{n-2}\,du. 
\end{equation*}
So,

> $\displaystyle{I_n(z,\ep)\sim2\ep^{1-n}\int_0^\pi |\sin(nu)|(\sin u)^{n-2}\,du}$ for $n\ge1$.

In particular, for $n=1$ we get $I_n(z,\ep)\to2\pi$.

It remains to consider the case $0<n<1$. Let $a>0$ vary with $\ep$ in any way such that $a\downarrow0$ and $\ep=o(a)$, so that $\de=o(a)$. 
then 
\begin{equation*}
 J_n^-(\de)=\int_\de^a+\int_a^{\pi/2}, \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
where 
\begin{equation*}
 \int_\de^a:=\int_\de^a |\sin(n(\pi-v))|\,(\sin v)^{n-2}\,dv
 \sim\sin(n\pi)\int_\de^a v^{n-2}\,dv
 \sim\sin(n\pi)\frac{\de^{n-1}}{1-n}, \tag{4}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 \Big|\int_a^{\pi/2}\Big|\le\int_a^{\pi/2}v^{n-2}\,dv=o(\de^{n-1}). \tag{5}
\end{equation*}
Collecting the pieces (1), (1a), (2), (3), (4), and (5), we see that

> $\displaystyle{I_n(z,\ep)\to2z^{1-n}\frac{\sin(n\pi)}{1-n}}$ for $n\in(0,1)$.

Comment: This does not work out when $n=1$ as you should not get the $\epsilon^{-1}$ asymptotic.

Comment: @Ali : Oops! Previously, by mistake, I put $|\sin u|^n$ into the denominator, rather than the numerator. Now it's only significantly simpler, and I do get your $2\pi$ for $n=1$.

Comment: I don't think your solution is correct for the case when $n=\frac{1}{2}$, but it is correct for all the other cases. For the case $n=\frac{1}{2}$ there always is a strong singularity at one of the end points depending on the branch cut that will cancel out the $\epsilon^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: @Ali : I have fixed the mistake. In fact, all values of $n\in(0,1)$ are like $n=1/2$.

Comment: yes this is what I meant as well.